# Spring Data JPA Mapping Exception No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I am trying to use a projection and am getting the following error.  Not sure what the issue is.

Here is the projection:

```
public interface UserMini {

    Long getApproverKey();
    String getEmailAddress();
    String getFirstName();
    String getLastName();
    Long getUserKey();
    String getUserName();

}
```

Here is the Query in the repository:

```
@RestResource(path="getUserMini")
@Query(value="SELECT approverKey, emailAddress, firstName, lastName, userKey, userName  FROM [dbo].BdmUser WHERE userKey = :userKey ", nativeQuery=true)
UserMini getUserMini(@Param("userKey") long userKey);
```

Here is the Entity

```
@Table (name="[BdmUser]")
@Entity
public class BdmUser {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long    userKey;

private Long    priceListKey;
private String  firstName;
private String  lastName;
private String  userName;
private String  emailAddress;
private String  password;
private Boolean active;
private Long    approverKey;
private BigDecimal  orderLimit;
private Long    salesOfficeKey;
private Long    reportsToId;
private Boolean requiresOrderApproval;
private Date    lastLoginDate;
private String rowIsCurrent;
private Date rowStartDate;
private Date rowEndDate;

@Column(name="HashByteValueType1", updatable=false, insertable=false)   
private String  hashByteValueType1;
@Column(name="HashByteValueType2", updatable=false, insertable=false)   
private String  hashByteValueType2;
private String  rowChangeReason;
@Column(name="DQScoreKey")
private Integer     dqScoreKey;
private Integer     insertAuditKey;
private Integer     updateAuditKey;
```

Comment: -9 is `java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR`, which should be pretty common. What dialect are you using?

Comment: sqlserver.datasource.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect

Comment: Have tried setting to SQLServer2012Dialect and creating a custom dialect to no avail ...                                                                     
                                                                                                            public class CustomSQLServer2012Dialect extends SQLServer2012Dialect {

     public CustomSQLServer2012Dialect() {
         super();
         registerHibernateType(NVARCHAR, StringType.INSTANCE.getName());
     }

 }

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast the NVARCHAR to VARCHAR in your query

```
CONVERT(varchar,theNVarcharColumn)
```

Comment: Thanks, that resolved the JDBC -9 issue but no result was passed back.  The SQL statement works in SSMS .....
SELECT approverKey, CONVERT(varchar,emailAddress) as emailAddress, CONVERT(varchar,firstName) as firstName, CONVERT(varchar,lastName) as lastName, userKey, CONVERT(varchar,userName) as userName  FROM [dbo].BdmUser WHERE userKey = 13636